# java: how can I convert double precision numbers to decimal

Tags: java, matlab, decimal, double-precision

I want to convert double precision numbers to decimal .

for example I have 23.43, the double value would be (using matlab) : 174 71 255 122 20 110 55 64
now having this how can I write a java program that gives me 23.43 ?

and here is the calculation of double precision in matlab :

MATLAB constructs the double data type according to IEEE Standard 754 for double precision. Any value stored as a double requires 64 bits, formatted as shown in the table below:

Bits
Usage

63
Sign (0 = positive, 1 = negative)

62 to 52
Exponent, biased by 1023

51 to 0
Fraction f of the number 1.f

Comment: In what bizarro way are you converting 23.43 that it gives you that monstrosity? :-)

Comment: What is `174 71 255 122 20 110 55 64 ` ?

Comment: Why can't you use 23.43 in the java program?

Comment: matlab gives me that number and I want to convert it

Comment: @melisazand I think that the problem is how are you getting "that" in matlab rather that a simple 23.43. You should try to fix the output in matlab, not in java.

Comment: actually it's not possible . I want to send data from matlab and use that in my app .  I should use double other wise the data would not send completely . and the problem with double is that matlab convert it to this strange format !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(double);
double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(long);
```

Comment: Looks like what you have is a byte array. You'll need to convert your numbers to a long first to use this answer, it shouldn't be complicated.

Comment: I tried to convert -22 now I recieve 4.668931E18 , first i convert byte to long and then double to long but what is this number ?